# Rename index column so i can plot on x axis

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I am trying to plot a time series of apple stock data for the whole year, there is command chart_series which I could use, but I want to make it myself, using ggplot.

I am practicing with AAPl stock data from tidyquant package, but it does not give a column name to the date column, I'm trying to add a name to it, but when i try it changes the column name next to it instead of the date column.

```
library('tidyquant')
(tidyquant)
install.packages('tidyquant')
library(tidyquant)
getSymbols('AAPL',from = '2021-01-01',to = '2021-09-23',warning=FALSE,auto.sign=TRUE)

              AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close
2021-01-04    133.52    133.61   126.76     129.41
2021-01-05    128.89    131.74   128.43     131.01
2021-01-06    127.72    131.05   126.38     126.60
2021-01-07    128.36    131.63   127.86     130.92
2021-01-08    132.43    132.63   130.23     132.05
2021-01-11    129.19    130.17   128.50     128.98
```

I tried this code and it doesnt work

```
head(AAPL)
View(AAPL)
AAPL<-cbind(rownames(AAPL),AAPL)
rownames(AAPL)<-NULL
colnames(AAPL)[0]<-'Dates'
View(AAPL)
```

Comment: If you are using `tidyquant`, then you will get a tibble as dataset `library(tidyquant);aapl <- tq_get("AAPL")` I am guessing that you used `quantmod` and the output is in `xts` format

Comment: so its not possible to change the name of the column using the method i employed?, yes the output is xts format

Comment: If it is `xts`, it is a matrix and `cbind` with rownames, completely changes the type.  You need `fortify.zoo(AAPL)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the OP used `quantmod` to get the data instead of `tidyquant`

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL")
```

It is an `xts` data which is built on `matrix` class.

```
> str(AAPL)
An ‘xts’ object on 2007-01-03/2021-09-22 containing:
  Data: num [1:3707, 1:6] 3.08 3 3.06 3.07 3.09 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "AAPL.Open" "AAPL.High" "AAPL.Low" "AAPL.Close" ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
List of 2
 $ src    : chr "yahoo"
 $ updated: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2021-09-23 20:26:13"
```

Therefore, if we `cbind` with the index or rownames, it converts the class from  numeric to character as `matrix` can have only a single class.  An option is to use `fortify.zoo` to convert to `data.frame`

```
AAPL <- fortify.zoo(AAPL)
names(AAPL)[1] <- "Dates"
```

Now, we check the structure again

```
> str(AAPL)
'data.frame':   3707 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Dates        : Date, format: "2007-01-03" "2007-01-04" "2007-01-05" "2007-01-08" ...
 $ AAPL.Open    : num  3.08 3 3.06 3.07 3.09 ...
 $ AAPL.High    : num  3.09 3.07 3.08 3.09 3.32 ...
 $ AAPL.Low     : num  2.92 2.99 3.01 3.05 3.04 ...
 $ AAPL.Close   : num  2.99 3.06 3.04 3.05 3.31 ...
 $ AAPL.Volume  : num  1.24e+09 8.47e+08 8.35e+08 7.97e+08 3.35e+09 ...
 $ AAPL.Adjusted: num  2.57 2.63 2.61 2.62 2.84 ...
```

---

Regarding the usage of `tidyquant`, it returns a `tibble` with already a column 'date' for dates

```
library(tidyquant)
aapl <- tq_get('AAPL')
> aapl
# A tibble: 2,699 x 8
   symbol date        open  high   low close    volume adjusted
   <chr>  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 AAPL   2011-01-03  11.6  11.8  11.6  11.8 445138400     10.1
 2 AAPL   2011-01-04  11.9  11.9  11.7  11.8 309080800     10.2
 3 AAPL   2011-01-05  11.8  11.9  11.8  11.9 255519600     10.2
 4 AAPL   2011-01-06  12.0  12.0  11.9  11.9 300428800     10.2
 5 AAPL   2011-01-07  11.9  12.0  11.9  12.0 311931200     10.3
 6 AAPL   2011-01-10  12.1  12.3  12.0  12.2 448560000     10.5
 7 AAPL   2011-01-11  12.3  12.3  12.1  12.2 444108000     10.5
 8 AAPL   2011-01-12  12.3  12.3  12.2  12.3 302590400     10.6
 9 AAPL   2011-01-13  12.3  12.4  12.3  12.3 296780400     10.6
10 AAPL   2011-01-14  12.4  12.4  12.3  12.4 308840000     10.7
# … with 2,689 more rows
```